# When does the center of a set of points lie in the convex hull?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Suppose we are given $n$ points $X_1,X_2\dots X_n$ in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$. I'm interested in understanding some properties of the ``center'' of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ w.r.t $L_p$ norm, for $p \geq 1$
$$
\min_{X} \sum_{i=1}^n\|X-X_i\|_p.
$$

For what values of $p$ does the minimizer of the above problem lie in the convex hull of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$?

PS: When $p=1$, the solution to the above problem is the coordinatewise median. When $p=2$ the minimizer is called the geometric median.

Comment: You should be able to show that if a point $P$ isn't in the convex hull, let $T$ be the projection onto the convex hull, then $||T - X_i||_p \leq ||P - X_i||_p $, hence the minimum must lie in the convex hull.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for the comment. I can see that it is true for $p=2$. Does that property hold for any $p\geq 1$?

Comment: @CalvinLin: It is possible for $p=1$ for a minimiser to lie outside the convex hull.

Comment: @CalvinLin Your argument works for Hilbert spaces where we know that for a convex set $K$ and any point $P$ outside the set we have $\|X-\text{Proj}_K(P)\|\leq\|X-P\|$, for any $X\in K$. But is this true more generally for Banach spaces? Is there any good reference which studies projections onto convex sets in Banach spaces?

Comment: for  $p\ne 2$  there exist counterexamples in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $n \ge 3$, see my updated answer.

Comment: In retrospect, it's not too surprising that this will not hold for $p \neq 2$; the $L^p$ norm for $p\neq 2$ doesn't respect $L^2$-isometries, while the convex hull does. So if you take a set of points in the plane and rotate them around a bit in 3-space, probably you wouldn't expect this $L^p$-center to come along.  Convexity is defined in terms of straight line segments, which are special in $L^2$ but not so much in other norms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer for $p=1$ and $d=2$. We are given $n$ points $(x_i,y_i)$ and we are looking for a point $(x,y)$ so that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x-x_i|+\sum_{i=1}^n |y - y_i|$$
is minimum, equivalently, both $\sum|x-x_i|$ and $\sum |y - y_i|$ are minimum.  It is easy to see that the solution in the dimension $d=1$ case is the median. So both $x$ and $y$ are the medians of respectively $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$.

[image: green point optimal]

Let $A$ be a point in the set with $x$ coordinate the median, and $B$ a point in the set with the $y$ coordinate the median. If $A=B$, we are done. Otherwise, the intersection of the vertical through $A$  and horizontal through $B$ will be the optimal point. Now to show that the green point is in the convex hull, it is enough to show that there exists a red point in the (cf. the picture) third quadrant. Note that there are at least $[n/2]$ points to the left of $A$. It all these were strictly below the vertical through $B$ we would have $[n/2]+1$ ($1$ counts $A$) points strictly below $B$, a contradiction.

$\bf{Added:}$  Here is a counterexample for $3$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $A=(0,1,3)$,$B=(1,3,0)$, $C=(3,0,1)$.  The median point $(1,1,1)$ (the unique minimizer) does not lie in the plane spanned by $A$, $B$, $C$ of equation: $x+y+z=4$. We can now consider the points $A$, $B$, $C$ with some multiplicity $(2k+1)$ and then wiggle them a bit to get a counterexample with $3(2k+1)$ points in general position.

The same idea works in spaces of odd dimension.

Also, whenever we have a counterexample for an odd number of points (odd implies unique minimizer) for the metric $L_1$, we get a counterexample for the $L_p$ metric, for all $p>1$ close enough to $1$.

$\bf{Added:}$ Here is counterexample for the metric $L_p$, $p>1$, $p\ne 2$. Since the norm $L_p$ is strictly convex the minimizer is unique.

Consider $n\ge 3$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A_i = (0,0,\ldots, 1, \ldots, 0) = (\delta_{ik})_{k=1}^n$. Since this set is invariant under the permutation of coordinates, the corresponding minimizer is also invariant, that is all its coordinates are equal. Now we  only have to check that $(1/n, \ldots, 1/n)$ is not a minimizer (recall  $p\ne 2) $. For this it is enough to show that the function
$$[0,1]\ni t \mapsto (n-1) t^p + (1-t)^p$$
is not minimum at $t=1/n$. Now check that the derivative at $t=1/n$ equals $$\frac{p}{n^{p-1}}( (n-1) - (n-1)^{p-1}) \ne 0$$

By fattenning and wiggling we can also get a counterexample with points in generic position.

Comment: It is possible for a minimiser to lie outside the convex hull, even in the $p=1,d=2$ case.

Comment: @copper.hat: I see. so my proof works only for an odd number of points.

Comment: Well, it works for an odd number of points for all $d$, but not for an even number of points. I have not been able to show that **a** minimiser lies in the convex hull in this case.

Comment: @copper.hat:  I say the proof can be adapted to show that for an even number of points some minimizer lies in the convex hull ( $d=2$ case)

Comment: Yes, that seems likely to me, but my intuition for $p \ne 2$ has been way off many times over the years. The fact that it doesn't drop out of the first order conditions makes be a little wary.

Comment: @copper.hat: I don't know what happens for odd number of points ( unique minimizer) in say $\mathbb{R}^3$, perhaps true (?)

Comment: Well, for $p=1$ if you pick a point outside the convex hull at which $f$ is differentiable then the components of the derivative are odd integers hence non zero, so can't be a minimiser.

Comment: @copper.hat: three points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is almost never true, check the counterexample added, it makes sense if you think about it...

Comment: Uurgh, I see my error. By picking a differentiable point I am guaranteeing that the derivative is non zero.

Comment: It is weird, the minimiser is not even in the affine hull of the points. Nice counterexample.

Comment: @copper.hat:  Thank you!   managed to get the counterexample for any $p>1$, $p\ne 2$, ($d>1$ )... please take a look

Comment: Excellent! Another stab at my intuition :-).

Comment: @orangeskid Interesting counterexamples! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @v1105: You are very welcome, excellent question too!  Btw, from this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557207/moving-closer-to-a-convex-set/3558107#3558107 it follows that for $d=2$ we always have a minimizer in the convex hull, no matter what the norm is.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer for $p=2$ (the easy case).

In all cases $f$ is convex and $\lim_{\|x\|_p \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ so a minimiser exists.

Suppose $x \notin \operatorname{co} \{ x_k \}$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and
${\partial f(x) \over \partial x}= \sum_k {(x - x_k)^T \over \|x-x_k\|_2}$. If ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} = 0$ then an easy computation shows that $x \in \operatorname{co} \{ x_k \}$, a contradiction. Hence $x$ cannot be a minimiser.

Partial counterexample for $p=1$.

Let the points be $(0,0), (2,0), (2,0), (-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1)$ (yes, some points are repeated). It is easy to see that the minimisers are the square $[-1,0]\times [0,1]$, but not all of these points lie in the convex hull.

Comment: almost any $2$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$  are a counterexample, say $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ being the simplest.

Comment: I see now, but I thought it was true until I hit the more complicated example and enough of my day has been spent trying to prove the $p=1$ case already :-).

Comment: must say it took your example to see what's going on.  and now I see that if we take an even $\le d$ number of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ in general position then we still have : minimizer set of dimension $d$ but convex hull of dimension $\le d-1$.